# Как грамотно организовать JS код в ООП стиле разнесенный по файлам?

Tags: javascript, ооп

Не могу до конца понять структуру того, как должен действовать ООП код, чтобы получать доступ к родительским свойствам конструктора. При этом не ясно, где создавать и вызывать объекты.

Допустим у меня есть два класса, это `app` - мой главный класс, `map` - класс с картой, который дочерний класса `app`

Я имею следующий код класса `app`

```
class App {
    constructor() {
        this.app = document.querySelector('#city');
    }

    init() {

    }
}

const app = new App();

app.init();

export default function () {
    return App;
}
```

Отсюда я экспортирую весь класс целиком, чтобы получить доступ к его конструктору в другом файле. Код представлен ниже:

```
import App from '../index.js'; //забираю мой класс

class Map extends App { //Создаю дочерний класс
    constructor() {
        super();
        console.log(this.app); //здесь почему то приходит undefined??
    }

   // ... my methods
}
```

Вопрос в том почему `undefined`? И второй вопрос, где нужно создавать объект от класса `map`. То есть мне нужно эскпортировать класс и в родительском потом создавать объект, и обращаться к методам? или как-то по-другому? При этом нужно учесть что у класса `map` будут тоже подклассы.

Я буду очень благодарен, если кто-то скинет пример. Или хотя бы ссылочку на грамотно организованный код, чтобы посмотреть.

Comment: _где нужно создавать объект_ - там, где ты собираешься его использовать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что экспортируется не `App`, а функция, которая возвращает `App`.

Таким образом на самом деле в этом случае:

```
import App from '../index.js'; //забираю мой класс
```

В `App` будет просто `function (){ return ...}`, а не ожидаемый конструктор.

Для решения, нужно либо вызывать эту функцию:

```
class Map extends App() { //Создаю дочерний класс
```

Либо экспортировать сам `App`

```
export default App;
```

```js
var App1 = function() {
  class App {
    constructor() {
      this.app = document.querySelector('#city');
    }
    init() {}
  }
  return function() {
    return App;
  }
}();

class Map1 extends App1() { //Создаю дочерний класс
  constructor() {
    super();
    console.log('Map1', this.app); //здесь почему то приходит undefined??
  }
}

var m = new Map1();

var App2 = function() {
  class App {
    constructor() {
      this.app = document.querySelector('#city');
    }
    init() {}
  }
  return App;
}();

class Map2 extends App2 { //Создаю дочерний класс
  constructor() {
    super();
    console.log('Map2', this.app); //здесь почему то приходит undefined??
  }
}

var m = new Map2()
```

```html
<div id="city"></div>
```

Comment: Cпасибо, да. Это то, что нужно

Answer (score 1):

Сonstructor - специальный метод, служащий для создания и инициализации объектов, созданных с использованием class. Для производных классов, constructor по умолчанию:

```
constructor(...args) {
  super(...args);
}
```

У вас в родительском классе конструктор не инициализирует this.app:

```
constructor() {
        this.app = document.querySelector('#city');
    }
```

Вот ссылка на описание наследования https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/extends

Еще есть такие описание:

```
'use strict';

class Animal {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  walk() {
    alert("I walk: " + this.name);
  }
}

class Rabbit extends Animal {
  walk() {
    super.walk();
    alert("...and jump!");
  }
}

new Rabbit("Вася").walk();
// I walk: Вася
// and jump!
```

Как видим, в new Rabbit доступны как свои методы, так и (через super) методы родителя.

Это потому, что при наследовании через extends формируется стандартная цепочка прототипов: методы Rabbit находятся в Rabbit.prototype, методы Animal – в Animal.prototype, и они связаны через **proto**. 
Как видно из примера выше, методы родителя (walk) можно переопределить в наследнике. При этом для обращения к родительскому методу используют super.walk().

С конструктором – немного особая история.

Конструктор constructor родителя наследуется автоматически. То есть, если в потомке не указан свой constructor, то используется родительский. В примере выше Rabbit, таким образом, использует constructor от Animal.

Если же у потомка свой constructor, то, чтобы в нём вызвать конструктор родителя – используется синтаксис super() с аргументами для родителя.

Например, вызовем конструктор Animal в Rabbit:

```
'use strict';

class Animal {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  walk() {
    alert("I walk: " + this.name);
  }
}

class Rabbit extends Animal {
  constructor() {
    // вызвать конструктор Animal с аргументом "Кроль"
    super("Кроль"); // то же, что и Animal.call(this, "Кроль")
  }
}

new Rabbit().walk(); // I walk: Кроль
```

Для такого вызова есть небольшие ограничения:

Вызвать конструктор родителя можно только изнутри конструктора потомка. В частности, super() нельзя вызвать из произвольного метода.
В конструкторе потомка мы обязаны вызвать super() до обращения к this. До вызова super не существует this, так как по спецификации в этом случае именно super инициализирует this.
Второе ограничение выглядит несколько странно, поэтому проиллюстрируем его примером:

```
'use strict';

class Animal {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}

class Rabbit extends Animal {
  constructor() {
    alert(this); // ошибка, this не определён!
    // обязаны вызвать super() до обращения к this
    super();
    // а вот здесь уже можно использовать this
  }
}

new Rabbit();
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ. Но мой вопрос был другим. Я понимаю, как это работает. Я не понимаю, почему это не работает, если это в разных файлах

Comment: Хорошим тоном считается указывать источники копипасты

Comment: С удовольствием напишу) https://learn.javascript.ru/  У вас в родительском классе конструктор не инициализирует this.app:

Comment: Я не понял, почему идет строка _У вас в родительском классе конструктор не инициализирует this.app:_ - и далее идет код, в котором это свойство как раз инициализируется?